# How can I focus(ripple effect?) on Material UI <Button>?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Buton component in my React app. I want the button to be focused.

I think 'focusRipple="true"' is supposed to work but it does not change anything.

--index.js--

```
<Button
color="primary"
size="small"
focusRipple="true"
>
```

---

I appreciate your help.

Comment: try adding `autoFocus={true}` or just `autoFocus`

Comment: @bsapaka Thank you. Yes, it worked well. But do you have any idea why this is not written in the document?

Comment: it is a property of native HTML